# Unable to download GitHub plugin in Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am unable to download the GitHub plugin from Jenkins. Below is my proxy configuration

[image]

[image]

I am getting the following error:

```
 Failure -
 java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
  at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1317)
  at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1116)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:104)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install github plugin
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:450)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1313)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency ssh-agent (1.3), github-api (1.42), git (2.0), git-client (1.4.4), scm-api (0.1) doesn't exist
at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:488)
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:440)
... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it tells you:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency ssh-agent (1.3), github-api (1.42), git (2.0), git-client (1.4.4), scm-api (0.1) doesn't exist

Try downloading those other mentioned dependencies first (although they should have been installed automatically)